# Probability of X athletes placing in top X places out of a field of X athletes

Tags: probability

To give you a specific scenario

I have a field of 150 athletes that will get cut down to 75

If I pick 3 athletes, at random, who have equal chances of winning/placing, what are the chances that ALL 3 will place in the top 75?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\dbinom{75}{3}}{\dbinom{150}{3}} = \dfrac{73}{596} \approx 12.25\%$$ Let me know if you do not understand. I can clarify.

Comment: Using propabilities: $\frac{75}{150}\cdot \frac{74}{149}\cdot \frac{73}{148}$ Since each fraction is near to $\frac12$ we can approximate without any further calculation a probability of $\frac18=12.5\%$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thank you so much for the quick response. I don't understand how you get 73 from (75/3) and 596 from (150/3) ... What operation are the parenthesis delineating?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\dbinom{75}{3}}{\dbinom{150}{3}}$$ is another way of writing: $$\dfrac{{{_{75}}C_3}}{{{_{150}}C_3}} = \dfrac{\tfrac{75!}{3!(75-3)!}}{\tfrac{150!}{3!(150-3)!}} = \dfrac{\tfrac{75\times 74\times 73}{3\times 2\times 1}}{\tfrac{150\times 149\times 148}{3\times 2\times 1}} = \dfrac{75\times 74\times 73}{150\times 149\times 148}$$

Comment: This notation means that your total probability space is you have three people who can wind up in any of 150 places. The outcomes you care about are when there are 3 people who wind up in any of the first 75 positions. So, it is the number of ways to choose 3 positions from 75 divided by the number of ways to choose 3 positions from 150.

Comment: If you wanted to find the probability of all ten of your picks making the top 75, it would be: $$\dfrac{\dbinom{75}{10}}{\dbinom{150}{10}} = \dfrac{75\times 74\times 73\times 72\times 71\times 70\times 69\times 68\times 67\times 66}{150\times 149\times 148\times 147\times 146\times 145\times 144\times 143\times 142\times 141}$$

Comment: A great online calculator for these types of things is [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial%5B75,10%5D%2FBinomial%5B150,10%5D)

Comment: Thats awesome. So if I wanted to pick 4 instead 3 it would be ...

$$
\dfrac{{{_{75}}C_4}}{{{_{150}}C_4}} = \dfrac{\tfrac{75!}{4!(75-4)!}}{\tfrac{150!}{4!(150-4)!}} = \dfrac{\tfrac{75\times 74\times 73\times 72}{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}}{\tfrac{150\times 149\times 148\times 147}{4\times 3\times 2\times 1}} = \dfrac{75\times 74\times 73\times 72}{150\times 149\times 148\times 147}
$$

Comment: @hansolo you got it!

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thank you SO much. y'all are much nicer on here vs the regular SO

Comment: @InterstellarProbe sorry to tack on extra credit but...

how would the equation change if people got X choices (lets say 10) but only 3 of them had to place in the top 75? I know that their probability would increase, but is it as easy as changing to 
$$
\dfrac{{{_{150}}C_10}}
$$

Comment: @hansolo, that question was a bit more involved, so I posted my answer as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to your question in the comments:

Let $m$ be the minimum number of successful guesses. Let $n$ be the total number of choices. The probability of guessing a at least a minimum of $m$ successful times out of $n$ would be: $$\sum_{k=m}^{n} \dfrac{\dbinom{75}{k}\dbinom{75}{n-k}}{\dbinom{150}{n}} = 1- \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\dfrac{\dbinom{75}{k}\dbinom{75}{n-k}}{\dbinom{150}{n}}$$ Example: $m=3,n=10$: $$1- \dfrac{\dbinom{75}{0}\dbinom{75}{10}+\dbinom{75}{1}\dbinom{75}{9}+\dbinom{75}{2}\dbinom{75}{8}}{\dbinom{150}{10}} \approx 95\%$$

Basically, what this is calculating is the number of ways that $k$ people are in the first 75 while the other choices are in the back 75. We add up every possible outcome (3 in front 75 and 7 in back 75, plus 4 in front 75 and 6 in back 75, etc.) Or, we take the complement (total probability of 100% minus 0 in the front 75 and 10 in the back minus 1 in the front 75 and 9 in the back, etc.)

Comment: mind blown. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Approximate answer is $(\frac{1}{2})^3=\frac{1}{8}$.  However if exactly $75$ will be chosen then $\frac{1}{2}\frac{74}{149}\frac{73}{148}$ is the probability, since if the first athlete is chosen, then there are $74$ out of $149$ possibilities for the second and $73$ out of $148$ for the third (assuming two chosen).